# Action not triggered with checkbox created dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic, checkbox

When I created a checkbox with HTML the action is triggered normal but the problem when I create the checkbox with javascript(when I add a row in my table with button and I click to the new checkbox) action does not work.

This is my code :

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>

<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<SCRIPT>


    $(window).load(function() {

        $('input[name=chk]').change(function() { 
            if ($('input[name=chk]').is(':checked')) {
                alert("checked");   
                }
            else {
                alert("unchecked"); 
            }
        }); 
    });

    function addRow(tableID) {

        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var element1 = document.createElement("input");
        element1.type = "checkbox";
        element1.setAttribute("name","chk");
        cell1.appendChild(element1);

        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        cell2.innerHTML = rowCount + 1;

        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        var element2 = document.createElement("input");
        element2.type = "text";
        cell3.appendChild(element2);
    }


</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

<INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />

<TABLE id="dataTable" width="350px" border="1">
    <TR>
        <TD><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk"/></TD>
        <TD> 1 </TD>
        <TD> <INPUT type="text" /> </TD>
    </TR>
</TABLE>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Thank you

Comment: Given that you're using jQuery, why not use jQuery to do the dynamic element creation? Should work out simpler than the plain JS approach.

Comment: Sorry I have a question : why when I do that :

       for(var variable in temp_data) {
           $('#dataTable').on('change', 'input[name='+variable+]', function() { ... });
    }

It's not work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because your event handler:

```
$('input[name=chk]').change(function() { ... });
```

...is applied only to those inputs that match the selector at that moment - before the dynamically created inputs exist. You can instead use a delegated event handler that is attached to a parent element (or to the document) that checks the selector at the time the event occurs:

```
$('#dataTable').on('change', 'input[name=chk]', function() { ... });
```

The [`.on()` method](http://api.jquery.com/on) was added in version 1.7, so if you're using an older version of jQuery use [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) instead. (Unless you're using a *really* old version, pre 1.4.2, in which case you'll have to use `.live()`.)

Answer (score 2):

For dynamically generated elements, events should be delegated from one of static parents of the element or document object, you can use the `on` method.

```
$('#dataTable').on('click', 'input[name=chk]', function(){
   // ...
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you'r trying to attach an event listener (the `.change()`) to an element that doesn't exist yet in the DOM.
You should bind the listener only after creating the chackbox.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the `on()` method instead, provided you are using jquery 1.7 or above

See working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5WDjn/)

```
    $('#dataTable').on('click','input:checkbox',function() { 
        if ($('input[name=chk]').is(':checked')) {
            alert("checked");   
            }
        else {
            alert("unchecked"); 
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a *.live* handler for your checkboxes. Also, in the handler, you can use $(this) to get current checkbox.

Here you are: http://jsfiddle.net/edAv8/

Or you may use *.on* handler: http://jsfiddle.net/edAv8/1/